# Saving firebase snapshot as a variable to use in other places

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to save a firebase snapshot into a variable so that i could use it later to re write to firebase but upon getting the data, my app crashes. I realised that the code i have is just getting the snapshot directory and my second try i was getting the data i want but could not assign it to a variable.

I've tried accessing the data directly by using:

```
let name = Database.database().reference().child("Users").child(userId!).child("Name")
```

But that returns only the directory

Below is what I'm trying to do:

```
@IBAction func checkInTapped(_ sender: Any) {

        attendance.text = "Present"

        guard !checkInClicked else {
            UIAlertController.showAlert(message: "ERROR: You can only check in once for this Module!", vc: self)
            return
        }

        let userId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        let userEmail = Auth.auth().currentUser?.email
        let moduleName = labelText
        let name = Database.database().reference().child("Users").child(userId!).child("Name")
        let currentDate = Date.getCurrentDate()
        let currentTime = Date.getCurrentTime()
        let presence = attendance.text
        let ref = Database.database().reference().child("Attendance").child("Checkin").child(moduleName).child(currentDate).child(userId!)
        let values = ["Email": userEmail!, "Check in Time": currentTime, "Attendance":presence] as [String : Any]
        ref.setValue(values)
        UIAlertController.showAlert(message: "You have checked in!", vc: self)
        checkIn.isEnabled = false
        checkOut.isEnabled = true
    }
```

I'm trying to save all user data on button press to firebase but also trying to retrieve the "Name" from database to save it to a variable and assign it to "values". I'm still new to swift so any help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't actually retrieving any data from firebase when you declare
`let name = Database.database().reference().child("Users").child(userId!).child("Name")` , you're just creating a reference to it and not using the reference to do anything. Without seeing your database structure, I can't be sure that this code will work for you, but try this instead:

```
            @IBAction func checkInTapped(_ sender: Any) {
            attendance.text = "Present"

            guard !checkInClicked else {
                UIAlertController.showAlert(message: "ERROR: You can only check in once for this Module!", vc: self)
                return
            }

            //use guard let with optional values to prevent app crashing if value is nil
            guard
            let userId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid,
            let userEmail = Auth.auth().currentUser?.email
                else {
                    print("guard let failed: userID, userEmail")
                    return
            }
            let moduleName = labelText
            let nameRef = Database.database().reference().child("Users").child(userId).child("Name")


                // now we need to retrieve data from nameRef       
     nameRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (nameSnap) in
                if let name = nameSnap.value{
                //name has successfully been retrieved from database and safely unwrapped, do whatever you like with it now

                    let currentDate = Date.getCurrentDate()
                    let currentTime = Date.getCurrentTime()
                    let presence = attendance.text
                    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("Attendance").child("Checkin").child(moduleName).child(currentDate).child(userId)
                    let values = ["Email" : userEmail, "Check in Time" : currentTime, "Attendance" : presence] as [String : Any]
                    ref.setValue(values) {
                        (error:Error?, ref:DatabaseReference) in
                        if let error = error {
                            print("Data could not be saved: \(error).")
                        } else {
                            print("Data saved successfully!")

                    UIAlertController.showAlert(message: "You have checked in!", vc: self)
                    checkIn.isEnabled = false
                    checkOut.isEnabled = true
                        }
                    }

                }
            }) { (Error) in
                print("unable to retrieve name from nameRef")
            }
        }
```

A few notes:

- `name` has now been successfully retrieved and safely unwrapped, but the code isn't currently doing anything with it past that point

  - try safely unwrapping optional values such as `userID` and `userEmail` instead of forcing them, to prevent the app from crashing due to nil values being forced.
  - I also added completion/error handling to both of the firebase functions being executed, which you can find in the Firebase documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write

Comment: That actually worked perfectly with minor changes! Thank you so much!

Comment: How about if i have to retrieve many items though? Will i have to add another ```observeSingleEvent``` under the 
 ```if let name = nameSnap.value{``` ?

Comment: Glad it worked! If the items you need to retrieve are in different locations, then yes you would need to create a reference and call for each location, as far as I know. If they were stored in the same location, you could retrieve multiple values with a single reference and call.